# Css grouping multiple id`s classes

Tags: html, css

I have something like this:

```
<div id="attributes1"><span class="heading_fieldset"></div>
<div id="attributes2"><span class="heading_fieldset"></div>
```

and

```
#attributes1 .heading_fieldset {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 30px;
}
#attributes2 .heading_fieldset {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 30px;
}
```

how can I group the CSS to be something like (the next CSS is not good...it messes up my page):

```
#attributes1, #attributes2 .heading_fieldset {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 30px;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use:

```
#attributes1 .heading_fieldset, #attributes2 .heading_fieldset {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 30px;
}
```

You were trying to add the properties to the elements: `#attributes1`, and `.heading_fieldset` with a parent of `#attributes2`.

---

I don't know the full context of what you are trying to do, so this **might** not work - however, you could probably just apply those properties to `.heading_fieldset` without having to select the parent. That will reduce some of the redundancy.

Comment: now I get it, so the properties only applied to #attributes2 . It works now! GJ

Comment: @JoshC it works on FF/CHROME/IE/MOZILLA , I can`t wait to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In this cases I use classes

HTML:

```
<div class="attributes"><span class="heading_fieldset"></div>
<div class="attributes"><span class="heading_fieldset"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.attributes > .heading_fieldset {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 30px;
}
```

But, if you REALLY need the ids, use

```
<div id="attributes1" class="attributes"><span class="heading_fieldset"></div>
<div id="attributes2" class="attributes"><span class="heading_fieldset"></div>
```

which maybe is repetitive, but I prefer that than an awful and unreadable stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

I would say you should stick with classes as well. Save ID's for javaScript interaction or special things. This way you can style all `.attribute` the same - and then `.thing01` or whatever to get more specific styles. Your spans aren't closed, so that is a problem. Also, you probably should use heading markup if they are really headings. [jsFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/NxAC6/)  - What you really need is to rethink CSS a little and remember that it reads right to left basically. So when you write: `.thing .other-thing h1 { }` upi are saying, "apply these styles to 'all h1's that are inside .other-thing, which is inside .thing.' I hope that helps!

HTML

```
<div class="attribute thing01">
  <h2>Your heading</h2>
</div>

<div class="attribute thing02">
  <h2>Your heading</h2>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.attribute {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  /* example CSS */
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: .5em;
}

.thing01 {
  background-color: red;
}

.thing02 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.attribute h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```